# CRM 2011 Revoke Impersonation

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011

I am Impersonating a user to create the CreatedBy for Notes. But I only want to have it work with the Annotation Entity and use the normal admin to add the other records. Is there a way to associate it so the impersonation only effects one entity or if not is there a way to revoke the impersonation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the CallerId property of the service proxy back to the id of the admin after you have created the annotation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334744.aspx